# where the exchange rate table is stored in essbase?

Tags: hyperion, essbase, currency-exchange-rates

I am new in hyperion planning , doing some assignments with currency conversion and exchange rate table. I have created currency conversion application in planning and also create a exchange rate table in Planning.Both are stored in Plan-type(database).

I will refresh the application and database then application and some scripts are visible in essbase, but I can not see the exchange rate table that I have created in Planning.
So could you tell me where this exchange rate table is stored or view in essbase (EAS console).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

Editing Exchange Rate Tables:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17236_01/epm.1112/hp_admin_11122/ed_exchg_rt_tbl.html

This is for system 11. You might be on an earlier version.